# How to reload session values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am sending data from view to controller using ajax , modelID , catId etc and searching data from database against these parameters, but first time load session values but after that if i change its value cant not load session values.

```
  $("#ModelID").change(function () {
        var Cat = $("#Cat").val();
        var subcat = $("#CatID").val();

        if (Cat != "" & subcat != "") {

            $("#modalvalag").modal("show");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/Inventory/CatSubCatAgainstModal',
                data: {

                    Cat: $("#Cat").val(),
                    SubCat: $("#CatID").val(),
                    ModelID: $("#ModelID").val()
                },

                success: function (response) {

                    $('#noo').html(response);
                }

            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select Category Or sub category to complete this process");
        }

        return false
    });
```

Here is controller code:

```
public ActionResult CatSubCatAgainstModal(int Cat = 0, int SubCat = 0 , int ModelID = 0)
    {
       // var dta = db.ItemsCatSubCats.Where(m => m.CatID == CatID & m.SubCatID == SubCatID).FirstOrDefault();
        //Session["ItemName"] = dta.Category.Catgory + "|" + dta.SubCategory.SubCat;
        Session["CatID"] = Cat;
        Session["SubCat"] = SubCat;
        Session["ModelID"] = ModelID;
        var data = db.ItemAttributes.Where(m => m.CatID == Cat & m.SubCatID == SubCat & m.ModelID == ModelID).ToList();
        int c = 0;
        foreach(var itm  in data){
            Session["value"+c] = itm.AttributeValue;
            c++;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AttributListForValue");
    }
```

Comment: Your html elements  doenst must change also? on success ajax function? Are not you forgetting that?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer please? Which part is not working? The code where you "Set" the session variables? "Session["CatID"] = Cat;" ??

Comment: first time session load against all parameters but after that i am getting same values in session even change catid, modelid or subcatid

Comment: Session["value"+c] first time its load but after that unable to load it store previous values even i change parameters values..

Comment: Check the sesson Id on the 2nd post before you store the values and ensure its the same as the first time.

Comment: If you're saying the problem is that you cannot read the values from the session, then please also show us code where you're trying to do that. Right now we can only see how you are setting the values. Also please define "unable to" - does that mean you get an error, or the fields are empty, or incorrect? Give us an example.